# Working with multiple api url in enviroment.ts

Tags: angular

My Angular application uses a classic `enviroment.ts` file as a setup for Angular environment. The file contains the `api_url` variable as follows:

```js
api_url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest'
```

I also have an `api.service.ts` file that defines some generic http requests, using the `api_url` to build the endpoint path. For instance:

```js
  // Generic GET Method
  get(path: string, options?: {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, options);
  }
  ...
  // POST, PUT...
```

In my application, I need to access another endpoint with a different `api_url` address. Regarding security and Angular best practices, what would be the best approach to achieve this in Angular 8?

My thoughts were :

1. Create an extra api call from my back-end and keep using the following structure
2. Create a generic service interface on Angular and implement it according to the specific required service (first or second api)
3. Copy the `api.service.ts` into `api_two.service.ts` and add an `api_two_url = http://my.second.api.adress` to the `environment.ts` file

Thanks in advance for any shared thoughts and advices :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion,If you are using microservices the the third option is best suited. But if you don't want to use microservices then the option 2 is best suited.
Thanks

Comment: I will stick to that. Thanks also to [Ankur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7678320/ankur-patel) for pointing me out the same solution

Answer (score 0):

According to your through third option is best because in case future you have to use another different api_url than your can achieve easily.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an extra optional parameter to your get function, where you can pass an alternative api_url. Something like below.

```
// Generic GET Method
  get(path: string, options?: {}, api_url?): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${api_url ? api_url : environment.api_url}${path}`, options);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for you commnent. But I dont know if it will work since I will always use both ``api_url`` and ``api_two_url`` from my enviromment.ts file. Besides, what if need to add a third `apiUrl` on my environment.ts file ?